# Is Supergravity just Super String Theory without open strings?

Tags: string-theory, ads-cft, supergravity

I'm trying to understand the elements of the AdS-CFT correspondence. The definition I have in mind is a correspondence between:

- (A) a Super String Theory of $D_p$-branes and closed strings in a $10$d flat bulk, with open strings living on the branes
- (B) a $II$B Supergravity Theory where closed strings live in a $10$d bulk that is asymptotically flat and tends to $AdS_5 \times S^5$ near the origin

and the two are linked because the curved spacetime of theory (B) is the effect that the $D_p$-branes of theory (A) would have on a flat spacetime. Then if one chooses $p=3$ fun things happen in the low-energy limit.
My question is, **why is (A) called a SST and (B) is called a SUGRA?** I mean, they both have closed strings. Is the only difference between the two theories (in general, not necessarily applied to the AdS-CFT correspondence) the absence of open strings in SUGRA?

Comment: Well Type IIA and IIB supergravity are low-energy effective actions of the respective string theories, and conversely the string theories are supposedly their UV completions. I don't think there are "strings" in SUGRA as such.

Comment: @NiharKarve I did not have in mind the clear concept of SUGRA being the low-energy effective theory of SST, but this makes perfect sense: closed strings are decoupled in (A), so they are in (B) also, therefore the SUGRA of (B) is the low-energy theory of the open+brane sector of (A).